# machine key in web.config for SSO without using of membership

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there anyway to use the machine key solution to create an SSO between two websites under the same domain ,The two website have separate databases and don't use asp.net membership .
If i can't use this solution can u provide other solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "machine key solution" without Membership providers if you create your own authentication cookie. Using the same domain on both sites and the same machine key will make the cookie readable by both applications.

If you do not use an existing provider or Forms Authentication, you will have to do all that by yourself, of course.

Comment: so you say that i should create a cookie that hold my client credentials like the username or password or a unique id and check it when redirecting ?

Comment: If you insist on not using FormsAuthentication or MembershipProviders, yes. But NOT the password. Encrypt the cookie, too.

Comment: i don't know anything about FormsAuthentication ot MembershipProviders but from it's name i don't want to use anything about asp.net membership can u please give me an example or a link that implements FormsAuthentication ? or can explain what formsAuthentication is ?

Comment: [How to: Implement Simple Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx) - [Understanding the Forms Authentication Ticket and Cookie](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443/en-us) - [FormsAuthenticationTicket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx)

Comment: ok thank u i still have one more question : what do you mean encrypt the cookie too ? i understand that i should encrypt cookie values but what do you mean by encrypting the cookie itself ?

Comment: That's what I meant, the cookie values.